# Angular ng-show , não remove codigo C#/Angular/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, html, angularjs

Eu tenho o seguinte código que lista categorias:

```
<div class="row" ng-show="!TemCategoria">

<div class="container" id="categoria" style="float:right" ng-hide="TemCategoria">
    <select class="btn btn-warning pull-right" onchange="window.location.href=this.value" style=" margin-right: 20px" ng-show="!TemCategoria">
        <option selected ng-show="!TemCategoria">@Model[0].CategoriaAtual.ToString()</option>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model[0].CategoriaId.Count; i++)
        {
            <option ng-show="!TemCategoria" style="color:#000; background-color:white" value="@Url.Action("Index", "Produto", new {CategoriaId = Model[0].CategoriaId[i], area = "Lojista" })">@Model[0].NomeCategoria[i]</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>
```

Eu estou atribuindo o valor a variável `TemCategoria` assim:

```
@{
    var TemCategoria = @Model[0].TemCategoria;
}
```

Eu preciso que quando não houver categoria o codigo simplesmente não apareça e nem seja interpretado, porque eu recebo um erro porque categoria está vazio.

Eu testei quando tem categoria e ele esconde caso eu coloque `ng-show="TemCategoria"` e mostra se eu colocar `ng-show="!TemCategoria"` mas quando não existe categoria ele simplesmente da o erro de variável nula, ele simplesmente ignora o `ng-show`, alguém sabe o que devo fazer para resolver isso?

Ps:. Eu coloquei o `TemCategoria` em todos para testar.

Comment: cade seu código do angular?

Comment: o ng-show e ng-hide apenas trabalham com o `display` do elemento, ou ele esconde ou ele mostra. ou seja, ele vai ser interpretado pois ele existe no código. Você terá que fazer esta verificação de outra maneira, aconselho a fazer diretamente no c# pois o angular é "Client Side". ele será interpretado apenas após a compilação de seu código.

Comment: achei que o Angular realmente removia do codigo =/ , vou ver como faço para resolver isso do lado do c# , o complicado e que é para aparecer o dropdown apenas se tiver categoria, não sei se consigo fazer isso. mas vlw a responta ai .

Comment: @WilliamCézar ele pode remover, basta usar `ng-if`, veja minha resposta.

Comment: @WilliamCézar seu `TemCategoria` é uma varíavel angular ou C#? Acho que se você fizer esta validação server side, é mais fácil e melhor dependendo de sua regra de negócio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para começar, você deve entender o conceito de ng-show e ng-hide. Eles irão apenas controlar a exibição visual do elemento, ou seja, é o equivalente a usar `display: none;`, porém, o elemento html ainda será escrito na página.

O melhor modo de evitar isso, seria usando `ng-if`. O `ng-if` nem sequer irá renderizar o elemento HTML caso a verificação não seja verdadeira.

Outro ponto a observar, é o modo como você está usando as combinações, elas são muito complexas, usando inclusive diversas vezes dentro de um mesmo bloco de código, o que em alguns casos nem faz sentido. Veja a tabela abaixo para entender como eles funcionariam:

- `ng-show="!TemCategoria"` = Irá **exibir** quando **não** houver `TemCategoria` definida
- `ng-show="TemCategoria"` = Irá **exibir** quando **houver** `TemCategoria`
- `ng-hide="!TemCategoria"` = Irá **esconder** quando **não** houver `TemCategoria` definida
- `ng-hide="TemCategoria"` = Irá **esconder** quando **houver** `TemCategoria`

E com `ng-if`:

- `ng-if="TemCategoria"` = Irá **renderizar** quando **houver** `TemCategoria`
- `ng-if="!TemCategoria"` = Irá **renderizar** quando **não houver** `TemCategoria`

Portanto, você deveria definir o `ng-if` apenas no bloco inicial, removendo todas as demais declarações de `ng-show` e `ng-hide` dentro daquele bloco de código.

```
<div class="row" ng-if="TemCategoria">
    ... restante do código ...
</div>
```

Ficando o código final assim:

```
<div class="row" ng-if="TemCategoria">
    <div class="container" id="categoria" style="float:right">
        <select class="btn btn-warning pull-right" onchange="window.location.href=this.value" style=" margin-right: 20px">
            <option selected>@Model[0].CategoriaAtual.ToString()</option>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model[0].CategoriaId.Count; i++)
            {
                <option style="color:#000; background-color:white" value="@Url.Action("Index", "Produto", new {CategoriaId = Model[0].CategoriaId[i], area = "Lojista" })">@Model[0].NomeCategoria[i]</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Deste modo, caso **não** tenhamos `TemCategoria` definida, o bloco inteiro nem sequer será renderizado na *view*.

Comment: Bela explicação amigo, vou testar no meu código e volto para dizer os resultados.

Comment: No caso minha  'TemCategoria' é um boolean, eu coloquei o ng-if mas ele continua entrando..sera que tenho que trabalhar com uma variavel diferente?

Comment: @WilliamCézar Mas TemCategoria é uma variável definida no seu código AngularJS? Por exemplo, $scope.TemCategoria = true; ? Pois não sei se haveria como comunicar essa verificação com uma variável que não seja do escopo do AngularJS.

Comment: Então , engraçado e que quando ele tem categoria ele funciona perfeitamente , esconde e aparece, eu não tenho definido no meu código de Angular, está infromação esta vindo direto do controller do C#.

Comment: @WilliamCézar mas como assim, esconde e aparece? O objetivo do ng-if, é de mostrar ou não todo aquele bloco de código quando houver declaração de `TemCategoria`, ou seja, se `TemCategoria = true;` então todo o bloco vai aparecer, o select será exibido. Agora se `TemCategoria = false;` então não irá aparecer nada na tela, o select e todo o bloco não irá ser exibidos (considerando que você esteja usando `ng-if="TemCategoria"`. É isso que está acontecendo?

Comment: Me expressei mal , se eu troco 'TemCategoria'  por '!TemCategoria'  ele altera entre esconder e mostrar o codigo, mas apenas quando tem categoria , no caso eu estou escondendo um botao.

Comment: @WilliamCézar Provavelmente isso acontece por que ao usar !TemCategoria é o valor padrão, pois o $scope.TemCategoria nunca foi definido. Acho que você terá que fazer uma verificação dentro do próprio AngularJS e criar uma variável que controle essa exibição. Por exemplo, dentro do seu controller, ter uma verificação if(TemCategoria) { $scope.TemCategoriaNg = true;} e usar na sua view assim ng-if="TemCategoriaNg". Conseguiu compreender a lógica?